# Weird bytes when converting code point sets into binary

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, codepoint

I've asked the question [Transform patterns of code points in a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45694375) 1 hour ago: I needed to convert sets like `[$a-z]` into a binary like this:

```
01 24 // $
00 // interval between 2 code points
61 00 // a
7a 00 // z
```

I get sets like `[$a-z]` from the [UnicodeSet](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp) site. It just requires you to input a pattern and generate a code point set.

I've rewritten a bit of my simple, but non-trivial, UnicodeSet to binary set converter. Now, instead of reading real code points, I read their escaped form `\u` by enabling the **Escape** option on the UnicodeSet site. I did this because the browser looks to strip some characters from the returned set.

However my final output for the set returned by the pattern `[:age=5.0:]&[[:gc=L:][:gc=Nl:][:gc=Mn:][:gc=Mc:][:gc=Nd:][:gc=Pc:]\$_]` after converting it to binary by myself looks to have wrong surrogates.

[image: drugs...]

My function for reading and skipping an individual code point in the input set is `nextCodePoint`:

```
    function nextCodePoint()
    {
      u_ch = input.charCodeAt(inputOffset);
      __escaped__ = false;

      // Handle escape
      if (u_ch === 0x5C)
      {
        __escaped__ = true;
        u_ch = input.charCodeAt(inputOffset + 1);

        // Handle \u
        if (u_ch === 0x75)
        {
          inputOffset += 2;

          // Skip the left XXXX base
          u_start = inputOffset;
          inputOffset += 4;

          // Skip the right XXXX base (limited for messy patterns)
          if (input.charCodeAt(inputOffset) !== 0x5C)
            inputOffset += 4;

          return parseInt(input.slice(u_start, inputOffset), 16);
        }
      }
      ++inputOffset;
      return u_ch;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the input, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output of that function?

Comment: @Bergi The input is a file containing the code point set returned by the UnicodeSet site, where we put patterns such as `[:gc=L:]`. There's even one in my question. The output is so large and hard to determine that I can't put here.

Comment: @Bergi Please ignore my warning about larger code points. I looked wrong.

Comment: I think your question (as well as your previous one) would be easier to answer if you could reduce the code to a smaller example, which also doesn't need file IO but has a hard-coded example which doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Bergi I updated my question. I solved my problem too... Maybe I update my previous example without IO.

Answer (score 0):

My UTF-16 encoding was correct, however the issue was that I did look for `\u` escapes, but nor for `\U` escapes. The UnicodeSet site returns `\uXXXX` or `\UXXXXXXXX` in some parts.

Here:

```
function nextCodePoint()
{
  u_ch = input.charCodeAt(inputOffset);
  __escaped__ = false;

  // Handle escape
  if (u_ch === 0x5C)
  {
    __escaped__ = true;
    u_ch = input.charCodeAt(inputOffset + 1);

    u_upper = (u_ch === 0x55);

    // Handle \u
    if (u_upper || (u_ch === 0x75))
    {
      inputOffset += 2;

      // Skip the left XXXX base
      u_start = inputOffset;
      inputOffset += 4;

      // Skip the right XXXX base
      if (u_upper) inputOffset += 4;

      return parseInt(input.slice(u_start, inputOffset), 16);
    }
  }
  ++inputOffset;
  return u_ch;
}
```